# Laravel aimeos - Integrity constraint violation issue

Tags: laravel

I`m new to Larvel Aimeos. I have used the following command to setup Aimeos.

`composer create-project aimeos/aimeos myshop`

But I`m stuck on the following issue while installing the same.

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-pr 
oduct-custom-8' for key 'unq_msattr_sid_dom_cod_tid'`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Your trying to insert into unique column. Remove the unique property of the column so that you may insert duplicate value.

Comment: Are you using an existing database schema already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the duplicate custom price attribute when installing the demo data. This has been fixed in a new Aimeos core release yesterday, so please try again

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using this project https://github.com/aimeos/aimeos-laravel

So if you wanna to install the same project again you should create a new database to connect within your `config/database.php` file.

Or don't install the dummy data `php artisan aimeos:setup --option=setup/default/demo:1` that the project required because it's already created.